# Finding the cardinality of set given by $X$

Tags: group-theory

Let $F$ be a field with $7^5$ elements.
$$X=\{a^7-b^7 \mid a,b \in F\}$$
I have no idea how to solve.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Prove that \begin{align*}
  \phi \ \colon \ &F \to F\\
  &x \mapsto x^7,
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism.

Comment: How it can help to count?

Comment: If you prove that, you can show pretty easily that $X=F$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a^7-b^7=(a-b)^7$ in $F$, and $x\mapsto x^7$ is an isomorphism, we see that $X=F$